# Tool to automatically inline both CSS and Javascript into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do you know some tool to

**automatically inline both CSS and JavaScript external resources into a HTML file**?

The goal is to have a single HTML file which can be properly viewed off-line.

Similar to [some old question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code) (but the answers there seem to support CSS only, not Javascript).

Either of the platforms: online (web access), Unix, Windows is fine.

I thought that could be reached by replacing all:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>
```

with

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     And here goes the content of the x.js file
   </script>
```

and similarly all `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` with

```
<head>
 <style>
   Here goes the content of theme.css
 </style
</head>
```

(or whatever the actual syntax is)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and name your requirements concerning the OS it should run on?

Comment: Added the clarification.

Comment: Would the source be a webpage online or from source files you have on your computer?

Comment: @NickWilde - I will have the HTML file on my computer, while the links will be on the Internet (http://), e.q. to the publicly hosted Javascript libraries (e.g. JQuery).  | But if it's a problem, I can always `wget` all the resources.

Comment: okay then I *think* I have a good option. I'll just test it before actually recommending it (I downloaded it a while back but haven't got around to playing with it yet)

Comment: @NickWilde - that would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nick Wilde's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9997/6547) led to me another answer:

**[another nodejs project called Inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner).**

(I have only started to try to use that and haven't succeeded with my goal yet - as some bugs pop up)

Comment: The source code for "Nick Wilde's" WebCombiner contained a comment pointing to the Inliner project: https://github.com/newghost/web-combiner/commit/bb884be1f59d7bba1987717e40abdf9eaad8ca09#diff-b43cb973c33ca90055cc553fe24a62edR12

Comment: The Inliner tool has some bugs too. I've encountered this one: https://github.com/remy/inliner/issues/13 But other than that - it seems to work pretty well. E.g. `nodejs ./inliner.js -i "http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9983/tool-to-automatically-inline-both-css-and-javascript-into-html"` yields a large HTML file with JQuery and others inlined.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I've managed to troubleshoot the issue #13 and submitted a pull request to the repository. Works for me.

Comment: I used this inliner tool recently, and it works great. Currently, it does not inline already minified javascript (*.min.js). However, by editing the source you could get around that, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Installation/Usage:

- Install [Python 2.7x](https://www.python.org/downloads/) - **make sure to select the option to add it to the PATH var**
- Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
- Install [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279) . It'll work on any thing XP+. Windows SDK 8 won't work out of the box - doesn't include all the tools. If you have the VS 2010 redistributables installed already try unchecking them in the installer for the Windows SDK - otherwise you may have to uninstall them to be able to install this and then reinstall the newer version if you need to at some point.
- Install [WebCombiner](https://www.npmjs.org/package/web-combiner) Node.js package. Best to use cmd line `npm install -g web-combiner` **from the SDK commandline rather than the normal cmd line is easiest**
- run command line `inliner path.html out.html true`

These instructions assumes windows - if not windows the SDK obviously is not needed but alternative compiler *might* be required.

Any `<link href=` have to refer to local files or it doesn't like it (ie fatal error). This could probably be fixed fairly easily but it is a weakness currently. Worst part of this is it doesn't check that it is a css link so atom/image refs under `<link` cause problems too. 
Obviously that means the css/js have to be local but just going save as html page from Firefox or Chrome saves those by default so that shouldn't be a serious problem though slightly annoying.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. It seems pretty basic tool and has some problems, e.g. https://github.com/newghost/web-combiner/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but the closer I can see to your goal (a single HTML file) is the [MHTML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML). Ok, it's not a single HTML file, but a single MHTML file, but, you can include JS, CSS and much more inside, like images!

Microsoft IE is able to save a page into a single MHT file.

The Firefox plugin UnMHT alows you to render this file on every OS.

Here is an interesting page about it:

[How to open .mht files in Firefox on Linux](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/mht-linux-firefox.html)

Comment: he said that if he want to to this, it's to "have a single HTML file which can be properly viewed off-line.". So, this is another way to the same goal… IMHO, but his question is not clear

Comment: OK, I guess this has the same end result (view off-line), but the OP was thinking of a different *method* than what you've said

Comment: I know, and maybe it's because he don't know other method was aviable (I don't know), so, it's why I suggest this method.

Comment: @PascalQyy "IMHO, but his question is not clear" - please help me make the question clearer. What information do you lack?

Comment: If my reply don't fit your need at all, it will be clearer

Comment: Relevant: [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - sometimes the asker is asking the wrong question.  This answer *could* be the right answer, if so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this because I recently needed to do the exact task but this solution seems easier to setup....

You can install python then run `pip install htmlark[http,parsers]` to install [HTMLArk](https://github.com/BitLooter/htmlark).

```
usage: htmlark [-h] [-o OUTPUT] [-E] [-I] [-C] [-J]
               [-p {html.parser,lxml,html5lib,auto}] [-v] [--version]
               [webpage]

Converts a webpage including external resources into a single HTML file. Note
that resources loaded with JavaScript will not be handled by this program, it
will only work properly with static pages.

positional arguments:
  webpage               URL or path of webpage to convert. If not specified,
                        read from STDIN.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        File to write output. Defaults to STDOUT.
  -E, --ignore-errors   Ignores unreadable resources
  -I, --ignore-images   Ignores images during conversion
  -C, --ignore-css      Ignores stylesheets during conversion
  -J, --ignore-js       Ignores external JavaScript during conversion
  -p {html.parser,lxml,html5lib,auto}, --parser {html.parser,lxml,html5lib,auto}
                        Select HTML parser. If not specifed, htmlark tries to
                        use lxml, html5lib, and html.parser in that order (the
                        'auto' option). See documentation for more
                        information.
  -v, --verbose         Prints information during conversion
  --version             Displays version information
```

The resulting html is printed to the standard output so you need to use output redirection to save it to a file like this: `htmlark http://example.com/ > inlined.html`

Answer (score -1):

This open source tool from Wildbit (makers of postmark) was just released and looks promising...

> **StyleMerge**
>
> Simple CSS inlining, for email, for C# and other .net-based languages.

https://github.com/wildbit/style-merge